# Are car rental contracts provided in English?

Tags: legal, car-rentals, language-barrier

Renting a car we need to sign a rental contract. If I rent a car in non-English speaking countries (Spain, Portugal) do the international rental companies like Avis, Hertz, Europcar provide an English version to sign? I don't like to sign something that I don't understand.

Comment: They have English versions on their websites.

Comment: Do I need to sign the same English version that is available on the site? Or do they say that it's the same and ask to sign in local language?

Answer (score 4):

Just rented from Avis yesterday after arriving in Austria. They provided me with an english and german copy for myself and I signed their german copy.